# Sourdough Starter Crust forming

Tags: sourdough, crust, starter

I am creating a sourdough starter and read to use a "non-airtight" container and store in a warm location for the first 24 hours before beginning the feeding schedule.  My issue is that 12 hours in my dough has formed a crust.  It is obviously drying out from the open air.  How do I prevent this and have it remain "open"?  I have it covered with plastic wrap.

Comment: According to Le Larousse du Pain by baker Eric Kayser, a crust can be formed and you should mix the sourdough consequently. Using an open container is not an issue and you should only cover it with a clean cloth (dish towel). I am curious about why the sourdough can form a crust (mine often does)

Answer (score 4):

You should be stirring ("aerating") your sourdough every twelve hours anyway. If a crust has formed, simply stir it in.

If the crust really bothers you, stir more often, cover partially or use a closed container - it works equally well in my experience.

Comment: I'd advice against a closed container. If the starter has conditions that are just right, it will produce a lot of CO2 and the container may burst.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify: by "closed" I do **not** suggest "airtight", but covered orwith a lid screwed on loosely. Thanks, @Anpan  for pointing out that detail.

Comment: That's indeed absolutely fine and in fact what I do as well. Please consider putting that info in your original post.